# create virtual environment by writing a python code

Tags: python

i need to create a virtual environment and then activate it by a python script.
when the file runs, environment is automatically created.
This is what i tried:

```
import os

def createFolder(dirname):
    os.chdir('/home/abc/Documents')
    if os.makedirs(dirname):
        os.system('venv myvenv')

dirname=input("Enter folder name : ")
createFolder(dirname)
```

Comment: Paste errors and anything else that might be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I would recommend you to read [this guide for Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify your question in order to help users to understand your problem.